# Vertically rotated Textblock takes up entire width as if it were horizontal

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textblock, text-rotation

I've wrapped the `TextBlock` control in a border so I could see what's taking up space:

[image]

Here is the XAML:

```
<Border BorderBrush="Cyan" BorderThickness="3">
    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource subtitle}" Text="{Binding Title}" >
        <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
            <RotateTransform Angle="90" />
        </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
    </TextBlock>
</Border>
```

The problem is that this is taking up much more room than I need it to, and if I set a static width to it, I get this:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: is there perhaps a LayoutTransform you could assign to a Setter Property and from there either increase or decrease the borders..?

Answer (score 6):

```
<Setter Property="LayoutTransform"> 
    <Setter.Value> 
        <RotateTransform Angle="90" /> 
    </Setter.Value> 
</Setter>
```

This happed because like in most Web Base Applications there is a series of events that get trigger / fired most of what we are use to seeing or dealing with happens in the Rendering Event.. by then the page has already been served up so to speak I am not 100% sure but I am really thinking that the LayoutTransform happens during pre-Rendering

Comment: Aha! I had to use LayoutTransform and not RenderTransform. Grazie!

Comment: Man I am glad I have a good memory.. glad I could quickly help you.. Vote UP..LOL

Comment: @SergioTapia The reason the `LayoutTransform` works is because it gets applied before the TextBlock gets rendered. `RenderTransforms` are applied after the TextBlock has been rendered and has blocked out it's space in the UI. DJ, if you wish to add an explanation like that to your answer, I'll vote it up :)

Comment: I believe that your response is correct.. but I am also wondering if there are some preRender events that are also being triggered and LayoutTransform maybe part of that prerender...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while creating textblocks on runtime and rotating them.
I solved it simply by setting

```
tb.Margin = .......
tb.HorizontalAlignment = Windows.UI.Xaml.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
tb.VerticalAlignment = Windows.UI.Xaml.VerticalAlignment.Top;
RotateTransform rt = new RotateTransform();
rt.Angle = -40;
tb.RenderTransform = rt;
```

it seems as if you don't set them, the transform is doing its calcs on the centered text and adding width to position it where you wanted...